# Exporting data from a (ExactTarget) Data Extension via Link from a Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, ampscript

We've created an Administrative Landing page which displays a list including peoples email addresses, names etc. My colleagues have asked for an "export" button that would allow them to quickly save out a "tabde.txt" or ".csv". While I could selfishly research this I am guessing it serves myself and our community to find out what functions might quickly serve that purpose. Bottom line question is how to create a link that would export a list of displayed fields from an ExactTarget Data extension as displayed on a Landing Page?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No Kelly, as I didn't really know where to start I thought it may save time to see what the experts do and help share that on SE. Didn't know someone would knock me down a point! (cringe) I thought it was a reasonable thing to ask. Oh well. I can try the jquery solution below, may also integrate well elsewhere but if you know the general direction I should follow within AMPscript etc I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: StackExchange can be a bit brutal at times, though it is geared towards being accurate and waffle-free, which is where this type of behaviour comes from. That said since ExactTarget is a new topic for SFSE I want to leave this question open. Good luck!

Comment: Are you looking to get all of the data from a specific data extension?  We do have [extracts](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/data_extension_extract/) but the set up may be more than what you are needing.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before, just enter all the data into a table layout and use the [jQuery table2csv plugin](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php). It works really well.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, In using the table2csv plugin it appears to create comma delimited text which opens in a browser window but not saved as a file. I'm curious to know if there are any similar extensions known which prompt downloading a file as I don't even know an easy method to copy/paste the csv text window so that it opens in a proper table.

Comment: @Amtera Can you Please give sugestion for  through landing page download dataextension data.

Comment: @UserSFMC I suggest to open a new question